error accessing downloaded mdb temp file in R using RODBC
I want to download an MS Access file (.mdb) file available online and handle its content from within R. I'm, however, having an issue opening it as the result of a temporary download.
I have used the code below (very classic) for other file formats and never had a problem before. What's new for me is the use of RODBC package.
wsc_url <- "https://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/cmc/hydrometrics/www/INRS%202017%20WatTemp%20Database/WaterTemperature_NHS%20-%20cleaned_20220607.mdb"
wsc_dir <- tempdir()
wsc_file <- tempfile(tmpdir = wsc_dir, fileext = ".mdb")
  
options(timeout = 2000) # Increase the timeout threshold to process downloads
download.file(wsc_url, wsc_file)
  
wsc_mdb <- RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007(wsc_file)

But I'm getting the following error message that doesn't mean anything to me:
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code -1206, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed

Strangely, when I download the file to a permanent location on my PC and give the full path to the odbcConnectAccess2007() function, it does work and loads the mdb in my R session. It's obviously not what I want to do, but figured I would test.
Any idea what the issue could be?
If you want to give it a try, the file is public and can be found here (https://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/cmc/hydrometrics/www/INRS%202017%20WatTemp%20Database/)

This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117792/ms-access-open-database-form-from-url

Try download.file(wsc_url, wsc_file, mode="wb")

Do you own a valid copy of MS Access 2007? Is it able to open the file from the URL?

@BartMcEndree I do have a valid copy of MS Access on my pc for files 2007 and above.

@MrFlick it did work! How come this works? Thanks

download.file assumes you are reading text files by default. It will translate some line ending characters because different OSes use different one. But if the data is binary, these "helpful" substitutions corrupt the file.  By setting the mode explicitly to binary, you make sure nothing is changed.
